# Scrape cannot find nested content using the Mechanize gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

How do I scrape a list of items nested in a scrolldown menu?

To help contextualize, here is the chunk of the view source that I am trying to scrape from:

```
<!-- mp_trans_schedule_disable_start -->
<select name="confirm1$ddlLeavingFromMap" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'confirm1$ddlLeavingFromMap\',\'\')', 0)" id="confirm1_ddlLeavingFromMap" class="input">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select</option>
        <option value="429">Beamsville, ON</option>
        <option value="438">Belleville, ON</option>
        <option value="277">Brockville, ON</option>
        <option value="273">Buffalo Airport, NY</option>
        <option value="95">Buffalo, NY</option>
        <option value="436">Burlington, ON</option>
        <option value="424">Cambridge, ON</option>
        <option value="440">Cobourg, ON</option>
        <option value="278">Cornwall, ON</option>
        <option value="434">Fort Erie, ON</option>
        <option value="428">Grimsby, ON</option>
        <option value="426">Hamilton GO Centre, ON</option>
        <option value="425">Hamilton McMaster University, ON</option>
        <option value="276">Kingston, ON</option>
        <option value="279">Kirkland, PQ</option>
        <option value="423">Kitchener, ON</option>
        <option value="435">Mississauga, ON</option>
        <option value="280">Montreal, PQ</option>
        <option value="437">Napanee, ON</option>
        <option value="124">Niagara Falls, ON</option>
        <option value="449">Niagara Fallsview Casino, ON</option>
        <option value="431">Oakville, ON</option>
        <option value="433">Port Colborne, ON</option>
        <option value="274">Scarborough, ON</option>
        <option value="427">St Catharines, ON</option>
        <option value="448">St. Catharines Brock University, ON</option>
        <option value="315">TC Kingston</option>
        <option value="310">Toronto Airport, ON</option>
        <option value="145">Toronto, ON</option>
        <option value="439">Trenton, ON</option>
        <option value="422">Waterloo, ON</option>
        <option value="432">Welland, ON</option>
        <option value="275">Whitby, ON</option>

    </select>
                        <!-- mp_trans_schedule_disable_end -->
```

I tried to focus on the CSS selector that is responsible for choosing an option, as well as, the option tag itself: `puts agent.page.parser.css("select").text` & `puts agent.page.parser.css("option").text` but both outputs turned up `nil`.

I also tried:

`puts agent.page.parser.css("confirm1$ddlLeavingFromMap").text` and `form.field_with(:name => 'confirm1$ddlLeavingFromMap').options[1].click`

Which also turned up nil.

and this:

```
require 'htmlentities'
require "mechanize"
a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}
@resultHash = {}

a.get("http://ca.megabus.com/BusStops.aspx") do |page|
    parsedPage = page.parser
    @resultHash[:some_data_name] = parsedPage.at_xpath("//h3[@class='right_col']").text.split(/\s+/).join(" ")
end
```

However, when I check to see if it turns up valid using `rake -T -A`, I get `undefined method text for nil:NilClass`. I do not know why.

I appreciate any feedback and thanks in advance!

Comment: Great, detailed question. If you are stuck for an answer in a couple of days, ping me with @halfer and I'll add a bounty to it.

Answer (score 1):

1.you should choose language first

2.you should use correct css selector (consider use plugin from selectorgadget.com)

```
require 'htmlentities'
require "mechanize"
a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
}
@resultHash = {}

a.get("http://ca.megabus.com/BusStops.aspx") do |page|
  #you should choose language first
  next_page = a.submit(page.forms[0], page.forms[0].buttons.first)
  parsedPage = next_page.parser
#you should use correct css selector
  @resultHash[:some_data_name] = parsedPage.at_css('#JourneyPlanner_ddlLeavingFrom').text  
  p @resultHash[:some_data_name] 
end
```

Comment: Doesn't `next_page` choose the first language (which is English)? Also, `#JourneyPlanner_ddlLeavingFrom` seemed to me to be the correct css selector. Is it not?

Comment: next_page is result page after submitting form with English language. you could use more elegant way to do it.
and I provided you woking piece of code, so yes #JourneyPlanner_ddlLeavingFrom is the correct css selector

Comment: Thank you for the assist! The language part was throwing me off